How to Move Specific IDs to the End in MeiliSearch Results with Laravel Scout?
How can I achieve this specific ordering on id with MeiliSearch in Laravel Scout?
$ids = [152,153];

$showcasePosts = ShowcasePost::search('')
    ->whereIn('tags.name', $tags)
    ->orderBy('tags.confidence', 'desc')
    ->paginate($this->perPage);

I want that specific $ids at last. like this:
[1,2,3,4,...200,201,152,153]

I have one solution in database query that I can achieve but not with meilisearch because OrderByRaw is not supported in meilisearch.
->orderByRaw(DB::raw('
    CASE 
        WHEN id IN ('.implode(',', $ids).') THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END ASC,
    tags.confidence DESC,
    updated_at DESC
'))

Is there any other solution?
