Laravel meilisearch scout, Is there any way to append specific records at last with pagination?
I am using meilisearch in my laravel project.
user_index : [id, first_name, views]

I am using order by on a column, let's say 'views', now i have some ids of some documents that needs to be appended at last.
So assume that
$idsToBeAppendAtLast = [5, 7];

$users = Users::search('')
    ->orderBy('views', 'desc') 
    ->someFunction() // here i want to use like orderByRaw to append $idsToBeAppendAtLast at last position
    ->paginate($this->perPage);

So output can be like in this order:
[1,2,3,4,6,8,...,100,5,7]
Is there any solution to this?
I have tried using orderByRaw but it is not supported in meilisearch scout.

This question was also asked multiple times last week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78618629/how-to-move-specific-ids-to-the-end-in-meilisearch-results-with-laravel-scout
